# Comparing key-value from two dictionaries Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key-value

I have this

```
a = [{'name': 'John', 'supporterId': 1}, {'name': 'Paul', 'supporterId': 2}]
b = [{'dependent': 'Erick','supporterId': 2, 'email': 'erick@gmail.com'}, {'dependent': 'Anna', 'supporterId': 2, 'email': 'ana@gmail.com'}, {'dependent': 'George','supporterId': 13}]
```

and I need to check if the `supporterId` between `a` and `b` are equal and if so put the `name_dependent` and email inside the corresponding `supporterId` in `a` so for example the output to this should be:

```
c = [{'name': 'John', 'supporterId': 1}, {'name': 'Paul', 'supporterId': 2, 'data': {'dependent': 'Erick','email': 'erick@gmail.com'},
{'dependent': 'Ana','email':'ana@gmail.com'}]
```

I have tried many for loops inside another but it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: One of the emails in the input data is not in quotes; is that intentional?

Comment: no.. just fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing it in a couple of steps.  First create a way to look up entries in `b` by `supporterId`:

```
>>> b_supporters = {d['supporterId']: d for d in b}
```

and then use that to build `c`:

```
>>> c = [d | b_supporters.get(d['supporterId'], {}) for d in a]
```

producing:

```
>>> c
[{'name': 'John', 'supporterId': 1}, {'name': 'Paul', 'supporterId': 2, 'dependent': 'Anna', 'email': 'ana@gmail.com'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves your problem:

```
c = []
for i, j in enumerate(a):
    c.append(j)
    c[i]['data'] = []
    for k in b:
        if j['supporterId'] == k['supporterId']:
            c[i]['data'].append(k)
    if not c[i]['data']:
        del c[i]['data']
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'John', 'supporterId': 1}, {'name': 'Paul', 'supporterId': 2, 'data': [{'dependent': 'Erick', 'supporterId': 2, 'email': 'erick@gmail.com'}, {'dependent': 'Anna', 'supporterId': 2, 'email': 'ana@gmail.com'}]}]
```